# Laminas API empty response due to invalid string Like double quote

Tags: rest, laminas

I am facing issue in Laminas API empty response when the string contain double quote.

Comment: Please read https://jonskeet.uk/links/stack-hints and provide a *lot* more information. What *exactly* does your request look like? (I assume that you mean the request when you say "the string" - but again, with more details we wouldn't need to make assumptions.)